# Mapreduce Hadoop WordCount Example for JSON file

Tags: java, hadoop

I'm learning Java and Hadoop and I've seen countless WordCount examples for simple txt files. How can I apply this WordCount example for the below JSON file? I'm having trouble specifically reading in each line in each JSON object for the Mapper.

file.json:

```
[
 {
  "id": 124,
  "tweet": "Hey its a beautiful day today!"
  "user": "twitter_username101"
 },
 {
  "id": 433,
  "tweet": "The worst superbowl was this year's for sure, waste of my day",
  "user": "username23"
 }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jsonReader and then apply word count on a list of objects by iterating it.
[JsonReader](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/stream/JsonReader.html)

Comment: MapReduce splits on each line, so you wouldn't get the entire JSON object in one go. You'd need to use a special input format just for JSON.